# jQuery.css() is not applying for all elements of ptag

Tags: jquery, css

The below script is only applying css() for first p only and not for the second. Help appreciated.

```js
var ptagsClass1 = $('p.class1');
ptagsClass1.css('background-color','yellow');
alert(ptagsClass1.length);// this is returning 2 elements correctly
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="class1">some content inside p tags 1</p>
<p class="class1"></p>some content inside p tags 2</p>
<p>some content inside p tags 3</p>
<p class="class4"></p>some content inside p tags 4</p>
<p class="class2"></p>some content inside p tags 5</p>
```

Comment: You're second <p class="class1"></p> is empty...

Comment: If you fixed your html errors it might just work... https://jsfiddle.net/9s3e46rj/

Answer (score 2):

The markup is causing the problem

```js
var ptagsClass1 = $('p.class1');
    ptagsClass1.css('background-color','yellow');
    alert(ptagsClass1.length);// this is returning 2 elements correctly
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="class1">some content inside p tags 1</p>
<p class="class1">ome content inside p tags 2</p>
<p>some content inside p tags 3</p>
<p class="class4">some content inside p tags 4</p>
<p class="class2">>some content inside p tags 5</p>
```